# Apply styles to parent using sass

Tags: css, sass

Lets say i have this structure :

```
<li>Something something  <input type="checkbox"></li>
```

How could i apply a simple `text-decoration: line-through;` to `li` content when checkbox is checked ?

I tried this with no luck using the `&` sass selector :

```
li {
 & input:checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
}
```

**EDIT :
I appreciate all the answers,however i was looking to do this using sass,i thought the `&` parent selector has this functionality but after i researched a little bit,i found out its not meant to be used that way.
Nevertheless,i found a solution without tweaking my structure or add javascript,i found out that bootstrap does not constrain you to place the checkbox after the `li` content in order to show it in the far right position,you can place it before and it automatically sticks it to the right,so i did that and placed the li content inside a `span`,so i just selected `input:checked + span` which gave me the desired result.**

Comment: In general CSS cannot 'go back up' to influence the styling of elements before (though you can sometimes make it look as though this is possible for simple styling).  Are you able to change the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. A Element has only access to his child and siblings.

With the siblings there is a neat trick where you can achive a similar result.
At first you need to move your checkbox at the beginning (html) so you can style the next siblings with `~` selector.

Then you can apply some css rules to the parent to swap back to order.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

div input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Hallo Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can´t, you need javascript or SassScript to do that, you can try this https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for this, but you do need to be able to add something to your HTML.

You can do it if you are able to add an element - put the text into its own div and putting it after the input.

Then use CSS grid on the li element, changing the order that the input and the div are shown. This just changes the visual order so you can still use the + sign to indicate the element which is the immediately following sibling of the input.

```css
li {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

li input:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

li div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

input:checked+div {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input id='input' type="checkbox">
    <div>Something something</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```